# print this binary code...backwards. in C

Tags: c, binary, radix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
/* converts to binary */

int main()
{
    unsigned int decimalNUM = 0;
    printf("Enter a number to be converted to binary.\t");
    scanf("%d", &decimalNUM);
    fflush(stdin);
    baseConv(decimalNUM);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
baseConv(unsigned int n){
if (n == 0) ;
      while (n > 0){
      printf("%d", n%2);
      n = n >> 1;
              }
return 0;
}
```

I know *how* to do this now, but it prints backwards. How would I go about reversing it?

Comment: Step 1: before posting your code, fix the compiler warnings.  Step 2: include the code in your question - unless it is many more lines than this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a way to reverse an operation like this, one way is to use a stack data structure.

Instead of printing the values in your main loop, push them on to the stack.

Then, once you're finished that, pop an item off the stack and print it, then keep doing that until the stack is empty. A stack is known as a LIFO structure (last-in, first out) and is a handy way of storing things for later retrieval in the opposite order they were generated.

Pseudo-code:

```
def baseConv (n):
    create stack s
    while n > 0:
        push n % 2 onto s
        n = n >> 1
    while not empty(s):
        pop n from s
        print n
```

---

I should also add that the statement:

```
if (n == 0);
```

doesn't really do anything useful at all.

Comment: I'd put the digits into an array; then print the array backwards (initializing the array to all zero's).  You'd get some extra leading zeros; but thats not too odd with binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid a stack..

You are backwards because you are starting with the lowest digit, converting it, and printing it.

You can go the other way round if you work out the highest part first

find the highest divisor for an int for your base  eg for binary  0x8000

divide your number by this  divisor
if its 0, don't print anything..  if its not, start printing
divide your divisor by your base.... eg binary    divisor >>= 1;
till your divisor is 0

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the most significant bit by turning all bits on (~unsigned(0)), then XORing that value with itself shifted right.  Then, test each bit from msb to lsb...

```
for (unsigned x = ~unsigned(0) ^ (~unsigned(0) >> 1); x; x >>= 1)
    putchar(x & n ? '1' : '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a string big enough and fill it with '0', place 1's into the string in reverse order, find first '1' and print the string from that point

```
int cursor, lead_one;
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*8 + 1);
memset(buffer, '0', sizeof(unsigned int)*8);
buffer[sizeof(unsigned int)*8] = 0;

for (lead_one = cursor = sizeof(unsigned int)*8 - 1; n > 0; cursor--) {
    if (n & 1) {
        buffer[cursor] = '1';
        lead_one = cursor;
    }
    n >>= 1;
}
printf(buffer+lead_one);
```